Can I add a standalone button next to the create button in Nova 4 in Laravel?
I would like to add a standalone button just next to the create button in a resource. without lots of work it's only purpose that it will work as an anchor tag to redirect to another page. What's a simple way to do so ?
I tried some solutions but without help me for example ->shownOnTableRow() , ->standalone()


Maybe check out https://novapackages.com/packages/datomatic/nova-detached-actions. These smees to do what you are looking for.
